# cocos2d-x ResolutionPolicy::SHOW_ALL show nice images instead of black gaps

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

When in cocos2d-x you set `ResolutionPolicy::SHOW_ALL` then it might appear black areas from top-bottom or from left-right sides. Can I cover the black area with some nice images?

Comment: it might be worth looking at the API Docs to see what your options are: `http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.2alpha0/d3/df4/_c_c_g_l_view_protocol_8h.html#a1cffba1e93904c18739b3a67171e7894` then perhaps look at that header file to understand this.

Comment: @GameDeveloper I am sure I have offended you somehow. You don't miss any opportunity to downvote me. If you know any document that I have not seen or found, then just post it, and I would appreciate. Is it necessary to downvote?

Comment: Please take a look at your question history. You ask a number of questions without doing any research. I always post links for you. You also ask 3-4-5-6 questions on a given day. This isn't how you learn programming. The days where you ask a lot of questions, look at how frantic they sound to get an answer. You don't just do that here. A search on the cocos2d-x forums turns up the exact same posts there too. I just think it is abuse. I still try to help you regardless but SO has the down vote system for a reason. That reason is quality.

Comment: And I am not the only one down voting you. Some of your questions have up to -7 down votes, which means it is more than just me. I'm not trying to be an asshole. I am however trying to do what the point of this community is. Help others but keep the quality up. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow

Comment: @GameDeveloper it is wrong to point out -7 down votes and not point out up votes. Fortunately, I don't care about the down votes. You can down vote all or half of my questions. If you search good, you may find it somewhere answered or explained. So don't lose a second to fight for the quality. Start now. Just down vote at least half of my questions ;)

Comment: so if you don't care about the down votes why did you bring up the fact that "You don't miss any opportunity to downvote me."? If you look, I may have down voted but I usually still try and help you. If you would like I'd be happy to just down vote if the question warrants it and not help you at all. It doesn't matter to me. There are others asking questions I can spend time helping instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can just add something into those back areas.

Instead the solution is to build a scene which already contain the nice images you want to add. The steps are:

1. Use this inside your AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching() to detect screen size:

   CCSize frameSize = pEGLView->getFrameSize();
2. Set a design resolution proportional to this frameSize maintaining its aspect ratio.
3. Put your "content" in the mid. Then, you have to calculate where are the "black areas" and add sprites to cover them. Keep in mind that for different screen the holes can be different, so you need to do some maths there and properly cover different hole sizes.

Answer (score 1):

So, doing ResolutionPolicy::SHOW_ALL sets the openGL view to  that size. That's why that can't be done with that.
On the other hand, there are many ways to tackle this.
What i did was :
1. Don't set the ResolutionPolicy.

1. Use a layer for those nice images/effects.
2. Create a new layer in that same scene and set the width and height of that layer according to aspect ratio of your content. And make this as your primary game view.

Comment: Could you show me a code example. The problem is that I don't understand how to set aspect ratio.